# actualizar varios registros a la vez en un tabla segun un codigo determinado

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla **tbl_detallesoperaciones**, donde tengo miles de registros por códigos de productos, donde el campo **Codpro** es el código de los productos, cada vez que se hace una operación se inserta un nuevo registro para el código del producto, o sea, tengo muchos códigos según productos, pero quiero hacer una consulta para actualizar los registro de un código determinado desde un Id especifico hacia atrás para ese código, donde Id es autonómico y es llave de la tabla, ejemplo si tengo:

un registro con:

> Id = 1500, Codpro = 150012, cantidad = 100, existencia= 16521,

pero para ese código el registro anterior es:

> Id = 1425, cantidad = 300, existencia= 16221;

el anterior registro a este es:

> Id = 1735, cantidad = 600, existencia= 15621

y así sucesivamente a muchos registros anteriores para es código, pero cuando cambie el registro de **Id=1500** a la cantidad a **200**, la existencia cambia según operaciones echas a **16421**, entonces quiero cambiar la existencia a todos los registros anteriores para ese código, según las cantidades que tenia en ese momento. Espero sus ayuda y gracias

Comment: Hola @refael si puedes coloca el código que tienes desarrollado hasta ahora para poderte ayudar mejor. Gracias

Comment: Gracias Yoel por responder, lo quiero es obtener un consulta donde me calcule las existencias anteriores para ese código al cambiar la última de código 1500

Comment: Esto no lo debe hacer la DB, lo debe hacer un proceso completo. Es algo muchisimo mas complejo que un query.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, si yo tengo un proceso completo en el update del controlador a la hora de modificar una operación echa en un sistema de facturación, por eso quiero obtener la consulta para completar la actualización de las existencias

Answer (score 0):

Hola a todos y gracias por las respuestas que me han brindado, me han dicho que deboo tener un proceso completo, aqui le voy a mostrar mi procedimiento para actualizar mis detalles de facturas, o sea, productos facturados, para cuando voy a cambiar a la factura alguna cantidad de un producto o cuando voy a cambiar un producto por otro,
aclaro trabajo con php y el framework yii:
aquí mi procedimiento en el controlador de la tabla tbl_detallesoperaciones que es donde hago los cálculos y operaciones y se guardan los productos facturados:

public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);

```
      if (isset($_POST['Tbldetallesoperaciones'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Tbldetallesoperaciones'];
        //capturar existencia revisar saldo antes de la operacion

        if ($model->save()) {
            $produ = Productos::model()->find('Codprod=:Codprod', array(':Codprod' => $model->Codprod)); //tabla de los productos a facturar
            $facturas = Operaciones::model()->find('nfactura=:nfactura', array(':nfactura' => $model->Id_sal)); //tabla de las facturas
            $subm = Submayor::model()->find('Codpro=:Codpro', array(':Codpro' => $model->Codpro));//tabla de las existencias de productos

            //importes en mn
            $model->importemn = ROUND($model->premn * $model->cantidad, 2);
            $model->importecuc = ROUND($model->precuc * $model->cantidad, 2);

            $model->SaldoIni = $subm->SaldoAct;
            $model->SaldoDes = $subm->SaldoAct - $model->cantidad;
            $model->save();
            //actualizar la tabla operaciones
            $cantra = $model->Id_sal;
            $query = "select ROUND(SUM(importemn),2) AS mn, ROUND(SUM(importecuc),2) AS cuc, SUM(imventas) AS imp, SUM(descuento) AS des, SUM(imventasc) AS rec, SUM(Recargoca) AS recc "
                    . "from tbl_detallesoperaciones "
                    . "where Id_sal= '$cantra';";
            $connection = Yii::app()->db;
            $command = $connection->createCommand($query);
            $row = $command->queryRow();
            $idmn = $row['mn'];
            $idcuc = $row['cuc'];
            $idimp = $row['imp'];
            $iddes = $row['des'];
            $idrec = $row['rec'];
            $idrecc = $row['recc'];

            $facturas->ImporteMN = $idmn;
            $facturas->ImporteCUC = $idcuc;
            $facturas->ImporteTotal = $idmn + $idcuc;
            $facturas->Imporventas = $idrec + $idrecc;
            $facturas->Descuento = $iddes;
            $facturas->Recargo = $idrec;
            $facturas->save();

              //para actualizar los saldos en tabla Submayor 
            $subma = Submayor::model()->find('Codpro=:Codpro', array(':Codpro' => $model->Codpro));
            $subma->SaldoAnt = $model->SaldoIni;
            $subma->SaldoAct = $model->SaldoDes;
            $subma->save();
            }
    $this->render('update', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

}
Por lo que ven si tengo el mismo producto y cambio la cantidad facturada, entonces me cambias los saldos iniciales (SaldoIni) y los finales (SaldoDes) de la tabla detallesoperaciones para ese codigo, pero si cambia el producto entonces el codigo afectado es el nuevo producto, espero me hayan entendido, pero necesito una consulta para actualizar los SaldoIni y SaldoDes despues de hacer la operacion del update.